# How to differentiate a tensor like $ A = A^{\alpha\beta} e_{\alpha} ⊗ e_{\beta} $ wrt $ x^{\mu} $?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

Given a tensor object: $$ A(x) = A^{\alpha\beta}(x)\;e_{\alpha}(x) ⊗ e_{\beta}(x) $$
Its derivative wrt. $x^\mu$ is: $$ \frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x^\mu} = e_\alpha(x) \;\frac{\partial A^{\alpha\beta}(x)}{\partial x^\mu}\;+\;A^{\alpha\beta}(x) \; \frac{\partial (e_{\alpha}(x) \;⊗\; e_{\beta}(x))}{\partial x^\mu} $$

How do you differentiate the second term?

---

Brief Motivation:

For a first order tensor, $$ \frac{\partial e_\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} := \Gamma_{\mu \alpha}^\kappa \;e_\kappa $$

Which invokes the notion of the affine connection, $\Gamma_{\mu \alpha}^\kappa $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the derivative of the product:
$\partial_\mu (e_\alpha \otimes e_\beta) =  \partial_\mu (e_\alpha) \otimes e_\beta+e_\alpha \otimes \partial_\mu (e_\beta).$

It works because $\nabla_v (T \otimes S) = \nabla_v T \otimes S +  T \otimes \nabla_v S$ for any tensors $T,S$.

Comment: Thank you +Hugocito that's what I figured but you've made it really clear for me.

I have one question: By definition, the derivative operator maps objects from some $ V -> V $, so it seems that the $ \partial_\mu (e_\alpha ⊗ e_\beta) $ is driving the property of the covariant derivative that you typed, kind of a chicken-and-egg situation.

Is this right (I'm new to this so I might be wrong)?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understood your question, you are using $\partial_\mu$ as a notation for $\nabla_{\partial/ \partial x_\mu}$ since you are using the identity $$\frac{\partial e_\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} := \Gamma_{\mu \alpha}^\kappa \;e_\kappa.$$

Usually we define the covariant derivative for vector fields and differential forms and then extend it to general tensors using the relation $\nabla_v (T \otimes S) = \nabla_v T \otimes S +  T \otimes \nabla_v S$.

Comment: In other words, the identity I used is true by definition. Of course, that may depend on how you define the covariant derivative of tensors.

Answer (score 0):

Covariant derivative is Leibnizian so
for
$A= A^{\alpha\beta}\;e_{\alpha}\otimes e_{\beta}$ you've
$$\nabla_{e_{\mu}}A= (A^{\alpha\beta}{}_{,\mu})\;e_{\alpha}\otimes e_{\beta}+
A^{\alpha\beta}\Gamma^{\nu}{}_{\alpha\mu}e_{\nu}\otimes e_{\beta}+
A^{\alpha\beta}\Gamma^{\nu}{}_{\beta\mu}e_{\alpha}\otimes e_{\nu}$$
which rearranges into
$$\nabla_{e_{\mu}}A= (A^{\alpha\beta}{}_{,\mu}+
A^{\nu\beta}\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{\nu\mu}+
A^{\alpha\nu}\Gamma^{\beta}{}_{\nu\mu})\ e_{\alpha}\otimes e_{\beta}.$$